# How to make a child entity automaticially reference back to parent entity when created using inline entity form?

Tags: entities

Here is the example:

'Parent' Content Type = Author

- field1: Name
- field2: Age
- field3: Picture
- field4: Entity Reference to Books (inline entity form widget)

'Child' Content Type = Books

- field1: Title
- field2: Description
- field3: Entity Reference to Author using prepopulate (need help)

Author has entity reference to Books using Inline Entity Form. So when creating an "Author", we can add "Books" they have written inline.

When a user visits an individual "Book" page, I want a field that links back to the "Author" who wrote it. How can I create this link automatically when creating a "Book" inline?

I assume I have to create a Book field3 that is an Entity Reference to Author that uses prepopulate. But I have not been able to configure this correctly to get it working as wanted. Any ideas?

Comment: if your the person who wrote this issues, http://drupal.org/node/1891588 then i think i'd look for a hook in the module to find the parent ...

Comment: have you looked at the http://drupal.org/project/relation module

Comment: No, I have not. But I would like to stick with references. Bojans provided this code here https://drupal.org/node/1891572 but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: thought it would work using project/ref_field, but doesn't...
http://drupal.org/project/ref_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been acheived using Rules:

Export of Rule:

```
{
        "rules_ifs_backlink_populator" : {
        "LABEL" : "IFS backlink populator",
        "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
        "ACTIVE" : false,
        "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
        "ON" : [ "node_insert", "node_update" ],
        "IF" : [
          { "node_is_of_type" : {
              "node" : [ "node" ],
              "type" : { "value" : {
                  "auction" : "auction",
                  "estate_sale" : "estate_sale",
                  "garage_sale" : "garage_sale"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "DO" : [
          { "LOOP" : {
              "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-ifs-add" ] },
              "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
              "DO" : [
                { "component_rules_create_entity_reference_back_link_" : { "child_param" : [ "list-item" ], "parent_param" : [ "node" ] } }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Export of Component:

```
{ "rules_create_entity_reference_back_link_" : {
    "LABEL" : "create entity reference back link ",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "child_param" : { "label" : "Child Parameter", "type" : "node" },
      "parent_param" : { "label" : "Parent Parameter", "type" : "node" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "child-param" ], "type" : { "value" : { "ifs" : "ifs" } } } },
          { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "child-param" ], "field" : "field_auction_ref" } },
          { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "child-param:field-auction-ref" ] } }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "child-param:field-auction-ref" ],
          "value" : [ "parent-param" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```